# Can you express this as two summations?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x}{1+r}\right)^{i} = \ ?$$

Can you write this as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1+r)^{-i}\  \times\ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i} \ $$

This is probably wrong, but in any case, how would I evaluate the summation?

Comment: Instead of taking the two versions of the summation to infinity, set the upper bound as 5 on both versions, and see what happens, term by term.

Comment: It is of the form $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a^i$. Does this look familiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cauchy product of infinite series gives us that

$$\left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i \right) \left( \sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j \right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k$$

where

$$c_k = \sum_{\ell=0}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell} = \sum_{\substack{i+j = \ell \\ \ell = k}} a_i b_j$$

So essentially taking the product of two series gives you summation, with a finite summation inside. You can see why that might not work for your method of factorization.

---

That said, your series appears to be a geometric series with ratio $R = x/(1+r)$, provided $x,r$ are such that $|R|< 1$. If so, then note that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x}{1+r} \right)^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty R^i = \frac{1}{1-R}$$

Of course, if $x,r$ are such that $|R| \ge 1$, then the summation diverges.